# Unchecked Vuetify v-checkbox icons not applying correct class for Font Awesome 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

For context, I'm creating a project using Vue 2.6.6, Vuetify 2.1.7, and Font Awesome 4.7.

When I use a [`v-checkbox`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls) component, or a component that utilizes the `v-checkbox` component such as the [`<v-combobox>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox) component, the resulting checkbox will have the correct checked icon, but an incorrect unchecked icon. The class applied to the checked icon will be `fa fa fa fa-check-square` (not sure whats up with the 3 separate `fa` classes, but whatever) and the unchecked icon will be `far fa-square`.

I'm able to bypass this issue by setting the property `off-icon="fa fa-square-o"` on my `<v-checkbox>` components. However, the `<v-combobox>` doesn't support this property and also it seems like a bit of a hack, so I would like to avoid taking this route.

My import file looks roughly like the following snippet. I've excluded unrelated theme declarations.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa4'
  },
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true
    }
  }
})
```

From what I understand, all of the auto generate icons should be using `fa` instead of `far` in their classes since I'm setting the `icons.iconfont` property to `'fa4'`. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but any input is appreciated!

Comment: Any updates on that issue so far? I'm having the same problem

Comment: So I ended up switching over to using `fa` (Font Awesome 5.14) for the iconFont property when I upgraded to Vuetify 2.3.8. I'm not sure what your versions are, but this did resolve it for me.